# Bloodhound & Typeahead JS autocomplete doesn't submit additional $_GET variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I have some javascript that uses the typeahead library that submits some data to my feeds API.

The feeds API can provide results for different sports based on a unique GUID.

- Sport 1 - SPORT169736
- Sport 2 - SPORT16547

Here is the javascript:

```
var fixtures = new Bloodhound({
   datumTokenizer: function(d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    minLength: 3,
    remote: {
        url: 'http://localhost/project/feeds/fixtures.php?param=%QUERY&sportguid=%SPORTGUID',
        prepare: function(query, settings) {
                settings.dataType = "jsonp";
                settings.contentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
                settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', query);
                settings.url = settings.url.replace('%SPORTGUID', "SPORT169736")
                return settings;
        },
        filter: function(data) {
            return jQuery.map(data.fixtures, function(item){
                return {
                    label: item.name,
                    value: item.guid
                };
            });
        }
    }
});

fixtures.initialize();
```

And have a chunk of PHP that has a conditional that checks for a sportguid and if it isn't available defaults to `Sport 2`.

```
if(!isset($_GET['sportguid']) || strlen($_GET['sportguid']) == 0) {
    $sportguid = 'SPORT16547';
}
else {
    $sportguid = $_GET['sportguid'];
}
```

However, the JS doesn't appear to submitting the sportguid when a user enters data in the field and the wrong sports results are returned. I believe this is to do with my javascript code but I'm not sure why.

P.S. the sportguid is part of the submitted Headers in the Network tab as well as the parameter (i.e. the search term entered into the field control).

Comment: If you're seeing the value in the headers on the network tab, I should `var_dump($_GET);` on the php side and see if it has the value you expect.

Comment: I added the param and the `guid` to the actual JSON response as a separate object. Will begin to investigate, thanks.